# Renaming attribute via pyQGis and data provider

Tags: pyqgis

I'm looking for a solution to rename a field/attribute via dataprovider (see the code below):

```
def modifierChamp(self,file_table,nom_champ,nom_champ_new):
    #vÃ©rifie que le champ existe
    dp = file_table.dataProvider()
    ind = dp.fieldNameIndex(nom_champ)
    if ind==-1:
        self.logFile.write("Le champ "+nom_champ+u" Nexiste PAS dans la table "+file_table.name()+" \n")
    else:
        # renameAttributes exists but I don't find how to use it !
        dp.renameAttributes(QgsFieldNameMap(ind,nom_champ_new)) # it does not work
        dp.updateFields()
        self.logFile.write("Correction du nom du champ "+nom_champ+" par "+nom_champ_new+" dans la table "+str(file_table.name())+" \n")
```

Comment: what happens when you run this?

Answer (score 1):

Following Python code in official [unit tests here](https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/blob/d61caab08d0e598601e65411317353a59d97c42b/tests/src/python/test_provider_python.py#L346), modify your code to :

```
def modifierChamp(self, file_table, nom_champ, nom_champ_new):
    # Vérifie que le champ existe
    dp = file_table.dataProvider()
    ind = dp.fieldNameIndex(nom_champ)
    if ind==-1:
        self.logFile.write("Le champ " + nom_champ + " n\'existe pas dans la table " + file_table.name() + " \n")
    else:
        dp.renameAttributes({ind: nom_champ_new})
        file_table.updateFields()
        self.logFile.write("Correction du nom du champ " + nom_champ + " par " + nom_champ_new + " dans la table " + str(file_table.name()) + " \n")
```